# Условие в триггере mysql

Tags: mysql, триггер

Подскажите пожалуйста, делаю триггер

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `updateBonusTable` AFTER UPDATE ON `character_subclasses` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 IF(NEW.level = 85) THEN
    IF(NEW.isBase = 1) THEN
      INSERT into `characters_bonus_85_lvl` (`charName`) VALUES(NEW.char_obj_id);
    END IF;
END IF;
END;
```

Мне нужно инсертить в таблицу `characters_bonus_85_lvl` только тот id который получил NEW.level = 85, а у меня получается он инсертить всех у кого значение = 85 в таблице `character_subclasses` в таблицу `characters_bonus_85_lvl`. Причем есть например id 123456 и поле isBase  у одного = 1 у другого 123456 = 0 мне нужно только то у кого = 1, опять же игнор, инсертит всех. Что не так делаю? Мне нужно получить в таблицу `characters_bonus_85_lvl` только тех у кого произошло изменение.

Comment: а может быть есть update, который меняет что то во всей таблице character_subclasses ? вот все записи с level=85 и садятся. И еще не понятно, что означает "123456=0" если это id записи, то как он отличается от записи с точно таким же id и isBase=1 (по крайней мере вы так написали)

Comment: @Mike это таблица с персонажами, у оного персонажа может быть несколько профессий, но главная профессия одна, поле id не уникально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мне нужно получить в таблицу characters_bonus_85_lvl только тех у кого произошло изменение.

Если нужно вставлять записи только тех, у кого прошло изменение, то надо проверять не только что новое  значение равно требуемому, но и что старое НЕ равно. Т.е. не

```
IF (NEW.level = 85)
```

а

```
IF (NEW.level = 85) AND (OLD.level != 85)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не большое уточнение, не нужно писать несколько IF? AND Работает? У меня почему ошибку писало.

Comment: Не нравится `AND` - используйте `&&`... см. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and ... а я бы вообще никаких IF не писАл, а проверку условий затолкал во WHERE...